# CheckStyle IDEA using suppression file for custom checks

Tags: checkstyle, intellij-plugin

I have a maven repo with custom checks which I want all the other maven repos to depend on. I want to suppress checks for some generated code in one of my repos. There are 2 ways I can setup suppression file:

1. Have suppression file in the custom check repo, then specify SuppressionFilter in custom check style xml:

   ```
   <module name="SuppressionFilter">
      <property name="file" value="${samedir}/checkstyle_suppressions.xml"
      default="src/main/resources/checkstyle_suppressions.xml"/>
   </module>
   ```

Then in the maven plugin section of the pom.xml file of repo that I want to run custom checkstyle on:

```
    <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle_suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
    <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
```

2. Do not put the SuppressionFilter section in the custom checkstyle xml. Have the same pom.xml setup for the repo to be checked. The suppression file can be placed local to the repo to be checked.

Both of the approach work with command line "mvn clean validate". But neither works with CheckStyle IDEA plugin for Intellij. The Intellij plugin complains it couldn't find the suppression file for the 1st method above.

I don't want to force every repo to have a suppression file if they don't need it. I wonder if there is a way to make suppression work for CheckStyle IDEA without having to have multiple copies of the same suppression file (1 in custom check repo, 1 in local repo).

Thanks!

Comment: Link to Github issue: https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/262

Answer (score 3):

The logic the plugin uses is

- does the file path resolve?
- does the file path exist relative to the rules file?
- does the file path exist relative to the module content roots, the module file or the project base directory?

If not, it gives up. So there's two possibilities:

- there's a bug in the logic. Raise an issue on GitHub please.
- it doesn't fit your use case. Raise a feature feature on GitHub, with a example to reproduce the problem and how you think resolution should be changed to fit your needs.

The code's in the `resolveAssociatedFile` method of https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/blob/master/src/main/java/org/infernus/idea/checkstyle/model/ConfigurationLocation.java if you're interested.